# How to solve configure checking

Tags: autoconf, msys, pkg-config

Nowdays I'm just trying to build libsamperate from source using MSYS on Windows, but i meet a configure checking problem I've installed FFTW & libsndfile before, their include files lib files and pkg-config files are all in the right place, but when I use sh `./configure` to generate makefile for libsamprate the output always mentions

```
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for SNDFILE... no
```

I also set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH(usr/local/lib/pkgconfig) and tried many times but the result seems the same

Does anyone knows anything about this?

Comment: The configure script leaves a `config.log` file behind that lists the exact checks that were done and any error messages they produced. It's  rather big, but have a look at it and try to find the section relevant to the pkg-config test (since it didn't find pkg-config, it couldn't possibly find SNDFILE either, so don't care for that check yet). If it won't give you a clue what is not set up correctly, try to add the relevant bit to the question.

Comment: I've checked the log file, but it seems not so useful information...

Comment: Could you explain something about how does sh.exe search for the 3rd party library?

Comment: `sh.exe` does not search for 3rd party library. `configure` script (which is interpreted by `sh.exe`) does. Besides you are not interested in how it searches for library (asks `pkg-config` (if the library uses it, but yours seems to)), but in how it searches for `pkg-config` (it didn't find it, so it than couldn't ask it where the library is installed). Well, it simply tries to run `pkg-config` (`pkg-config.exe`). If it's not in `PATH`, it won't find it.

Comment: I've installed the pkg-config.exe and the checking problem was gone :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your environment is not set up to run the pkg-config executable.  There are many problems associated with pkg-config, and it has become increasingly popular to suggest that the correct solution is to stop using it completely.  Unfortunately, if you are trying to install a package that does use pkg-config, you are not in a position to use that solution.  The closest you can get is to set PKG_CONFIG to 'true' or ':' in your environment.  This causes pkg-config to emit no output but always return true when it is run, so you need to specify locations of libraries and headers via the standard mechanisms (LDFLAGS, etc.).

pkg-config is great in that it allows a user (someone installing the package) to be ignorant of the standard flags.  The problem with pkg-config is that it allows the users to be ignorant.

As a package maintainer, you should stop using pkg-config.  As a user, you should either set PKG_CONFIG=: in your environment or in a config.site, or get in the habit of invoking configure with PKG_CONFIG=: as an argument.  (If you are using packages that rely on ancient autoconf in which you cannot pass such flags as an argument, I'm not sure what the appropriate action is, but suggesting that the package maintainer upgrade is probably not a bad idea.)

Comment: This answer is completely stupid. pkg-config is definitely a *LOT* better than passing CFLAGS and LDFLAGS manually, since certain libraries may require special CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. pkg-config is damn easy to use, and is configured with just the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, and possibly PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR if you're cross-compiling.

Comment: @Thomas pkg-config is very easy to use, and is a useful tool.  PKG_CHECK_MODULES is a horrible kludge that should never be used.  There is no need to set CFLAGS or LDFLAGS manually; that is what config.site is for.  PKG_CHECK_MODULES is a crutch for people who do not know how to use the tools, and it often causes problems for people who do.  This has been discussed ad nauseum for years, and the consensus on the autotool mailing lists is that it is an abomination.